# I can't start successfully boa constructor in windows7

Tags: python, wxpython, boa-constructor

When I start boa-constructor(boa-constructor-0.6.1.src.win32.exe) from the command line by starting the script "Boa.py", I got the message says

[image]

My python version is "python-2.7.7.msi" and I download wxPyton "wxPython3.0-win32-3.0.0.0-py27.exe"
O searched for files that contains the string "NO_3D " but I didn't get any can you help me pleaze and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you will require wxPython 2.8.12.1 to not get this error.

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.__version__
'2.8.12.1'
>>> wx.NO_3D
0
```

This is a pity, because the operation `…|wx.NO_3D` is actually a No-Op. So you could fix this particular issue by defining `wx.NO_3D` somewhere.

On 2.9.5:

```
>>> import wx
>>> wx.__version__
'2.9.5.0'
>>> wx.NO_3D
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NO_3D'
```

Comment: thanks nepix32 but can you explain more and thanks :)

Comment: @Lina: Not sure what to explain more, but I'll give a try: 0) Seriously consider an editor more up-to-date with current python. 1) Install wxPython 2.8.12.1 (you can use a virtualenv, if 3.0 is required) 2) Fix the code of the offending file (just declare `wx.NO_3D = 0` at the start of the `…\prefs.rc.py`). Very likely you will encounter more stumbling blocks.

Comment: thnaks nepix32 for your reply I did what you recommend me to do but now I have this error C:\Users\Lenovo>D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boa-constructor\boa.py
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\boa-constructor\Boa.py", line 16
    Handles creation/initialisation of main objects and commandline arguments ""
"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax